# How to add embed content to my website when sending a link?

Tags: html, web, embed

When sending many links, it shows some embed data including the title and a short description of the subject of the link. Here is an example: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAXpV.jpg)

How do I do that in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved using the opengraph meta tags.
When you share a url via social networks or other then it will display using content of the og meta tags of the related page.
Example :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Open Graph Meta Tags: Everything You Need to Know" />
```

[Here is a link with a good explanation and pratical examples](https://ahrefs.com/blog/open-graph-meta-tags/)